# Why was this spell cast in Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, character-motivation, fantastic-beasts

Near the end of ***Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them***, Newt casts

> revelio, showing that the Graves we see is really Gellert Grindelwald. As far as I am aware, the movie until this point had not provided any "tells" that Grindelwald had been impersonating Graves.

Thus, why did Newt cast this spell?